# Mongoose & MongoDB $Push is correctly updating array of strings, while emptying and refusing to update second array of numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am trying to update an array within a MongoDB collection

It successfully updates when fed the entire array, but the array of numbers breaks and loses all of its values when I use a `$Push` operation. The array of strings remains intact and successfully updates.

I am trying to update this

```
var transactionSchema = new Schema({
    items: [String],
    itemsPrice: [Number],
    });
```

With a single or multiple from value from this.

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
    itemName: String,
    itemPrice: Number,
});
```

This works when I update using this method

```
module.exports.updateTransactionById = function (req, res, next) {
 Transaction.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, 
    { new: true }, function(err, transaction) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     if (!transaction) res.status(404).send("No transaction item with that ID!")
    return res.status(200).send(transaction);
});
}

//    update empty transaction
// RESULT: transaction: {_id=01, items=[a], itemsPrice=[3]}
//    update any transaction with some array
// RESULT: transaction: {_id=01, items=[a,b,c], itemsPrice=[1,2,4]}
```

However, I have to send the entire pre-existing array with each update, which means I would need to query the transactions collection with a `GET` request before updating it, and that seems unnecessary.

I'm using the `$Push` method in Mongoose and it doesn't work.

```
module.exports.updatePushTransactionById = function (req, res, next) {
 Transaction.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, { $push: req.body }, 
    { new: true }, function(err, transaction) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     if (!transaction) res.status(404).send("No transaction item with that ID!")
    return res.status(200).send(transaction);
});
}

//    Try updating an empty transaction
//RESULT: transaction: {_id: 01, items=[a], itemsPrice=[]}
//    increment subsequent updates
//Result: transaction: {_id: 01, items=[a,b,c,d], itemsPrice=[]}


//      Try updating an existing transaction that looks like:
//        transaction: {_id: 01, items=[a,b,c,d], itemsPrice=[2,3,4,5]}
//      Run push update
//Result: transaction: {_id:01, items=[a,b,c,d,e], itemsPrice=[]
```

The request body seems to be valid. The casting seems okay, since it accepts the same exact request for the `findOneAndUpdate` method **WITHOUT** using a **$Push**

If this doesn't make sense, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

A user will click a button to contact the DB and query for the price of an item. The name and price of the item will be fed into a transaction DB. I know holding the details of the transaction in an array is not good, but bear with me.

These are the fetch calls I am using:

`GET` the price of the item.

```
function getMenuItemFromDatabase(target) {
var url = '/menus/' + target.id;
 return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
 }).then(function(res){
    if(!res.ok) console.log("Error");
    else return res.json().then(function(result){
        var returnedItem = JSON.parse(result)
         return returnedItem[0];
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });
});
}
```

`PUT` (by pushing into array) the name and price

```
function updateTransaction(target){
 getMenuItemFromDatabase(target).then(function(menuItem) {

    var data = {
        items:[menuItem.itemName],
        itemsPrice:[menuItem.itemPrice]
    }

    var url = '/transactions/' + localStorage.transactionID;

    fetch(url, {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function(res){
        if (!res.ok) alert("ERROR!")
        else return res.json().then(function(response){
            }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw(err);
        });
    });
});
}
```

I'm pretty confused why this is happening. I've tried looking over the code and playing with the `console.log` dump in various places, but I'm stuck at this point. I would appreciate any input as to what I must be missing here.

```
console.log(typeof(req.body.items[0])); // String
console.log(typeof(req.body.itemsPrice[0])); // Number ... so it should work??
```

I have tried pushing `req.body.itemsPrice`, `req.body.itemsPrice[0]`, `req.body`, but the `itemsPrice` array refuses to update for me.

This is a sample `req.body` that gets logged by the api
`{ items: [ 'Pizza' ], itemsPrice: [ 5.25 ] }`

I tried to construct the `push` query like this:
`{ $push: { itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice, items: req.body.items} }`

Comment: *"This works when I update using this method"* because the code where you are making that comment is simply "replacing" the content. You cannot just add `$push` in front of `req.body` and expect it to work. You actually need to construct the statements like they are supposed to be done.

Comment: Bottom line is for all the "long post", you simply don't tell us the **one** important thing, which is *"This is what the content of `req.body` looks like"*. That's all we need to know, along with if it's flexible to "change" the request input from how you are currently sending it to better accommodate your needs.

Comment: @NeilLunn will update with the content of req.body, give me a sec

Comment: @NeilLunn `req.body` simply looks like `{ items: [ 'Pizza' ], itemsPrice: [ 5.25 ] }`. Previously I tried to construct the Push query like this : `{ $push: {
  itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice, 
  items: req.body.items}
 }`

Comment: You need to use [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) when those are actually arrays and not singular items. The question really is do you want to `$push` and "add new array members" to the existing ones? Or do you actually want to "replace" the current arrays, in which case you would [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) instead. That's what you need to work out.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Yes, I wanted to "add new members to the array." I was able to get it working by doing this: `{ $push: {
  itemsPrice: {$each: req.body.itemsPrice}, 
  items: {$each: req.body.items}}
 } ` I guess I need to study the Mongo/Mongoose docs a bit better. I'm still not clear on why I could not do `$push{ itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice[0] }`, or why it was successfully iterating and pushing upon the string array without a problem.